# SQLite Left Outer Join not working as expected in Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, join, outer-join

I have prepared a left outer join query that should be returning non-null data when a record exists in my BLOB table that matches keys with a record in my INCIDENT table.

Essentially, the data and query looks like this:

```
Table A
   Key

Table B
   Key
   Blob
```

and the query I'm running, should show all records from A, and the 'hasb' column should be 1 if there's a record in B with a matching key column, or 0 if there isn't. So the query should look like this:

```
SELECT A.*, ifnull(A.Key = B.Key, 0) as hasb FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.Key = B.Key
```

Ok, so my problem is, this query seems to work everywhere I try to use it EXCEPT on the Android device.

Here's a SQLFiddle with the actual tables and query in question. Note that the query works there.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/89e7d/4

Anyone know why this doesn't work on Android? The device I'm testing with is a Samsung Galaxy S 3 running Android 4.1.1.

Comment: Note the left join you provided in your fiddle is not the same as the one in your example. You're joining in 2 conditions, not just one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating things with the `ifnull`.

This is the query in your fiddle:

```
SELECT ifnull( a.userid = b.userid, 0 ) FROM incidentdata AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN incidentblob AS b
ON ( a.userid = b.userid ) AND ( a.incidenttag = b.incidenttag );
```

This is the query I would write:

```
SELECT a.userid, a.incidenttag, b._id, b._id is not null hasb
FROM incidentdata AS a
LEFT JOIN incidentblob AS b
ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.incidenttag = b.incidenttag
```

Does it work? If it doesn't please, provide the SQLite version you're using. Anyway, I'm pretty sure the issue resides in the following items:

- Understanding that `null = null` does not return `TRUE` but rather `null`
- `null` values being present in both `b.userid` as well as `a.incidenttag` after performing the `left join`

Answer (score 0):

I know your query "seems to work everywhere".

However, I suggest you an alternative one:

```
SELECT a.*, b.ROWID IS NOT NULL AS hasb FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.key IS b.key;
```

Differences:

- Avoid `IFNULL` function call;
- `a.key IS b.key` will handle a null key value;
- checking `b.ROWID` is `b` row data independent.